# jQuery function in a external javascript file isnt working

Tags: jquery, function

I have an external javascript file with a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#save").on('click', function () {
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +
            encodeURIComponent($('#exportToExcelDiv').html()));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and a link that looks like:

```
   <a href="#" title="Save"><img src="../../Images/glyphicons_446_floppy_save.png"         
   id="save" name="save"></a>
```

but the function is not working on the link. 
Its nothing wrong with the linking between the files (tried an alert function that works)

And also the functions works when i type it directly in html.

Comment: Is `#save` added to the DOM after page load? Have you tried `$(document).on("click", "#save", function() { ... })`?

Comment: where you included external js fil? is that after jquery file?

Comment: Have you added jQuery library before the file has function?

Comment: In addition to all the above, please also check your browser console for any errors that may be being logged.